# RxJS Reactive Programming

Tags: javascript, chat, reactive-programming, rxjs

I would like to create a chat, with a facebook-like "xyz is typing" feature.

```
onKeydownSource.subscribe(function() {
  var typing = true;
}.bind(this));

onKeydownSource.throttle(500).subscribe(function(e) {
  var typing = false;
}.bind(this));
```

I use this snippet to register, when the user stops typing.

Now imagine e to be

```
{
    userId: 13,
    conversationId: 23
}
```

And my streams/subscriber to be

```
onKeydownSource.subscribe(function(e) {
  typingInConversations[e.conversationId][e.userId] = true;
}.bind(this));

onKeydownSource
// What should be here?
.subscribe(function(e) {
  typingInConversations[e.conversationId][e.userId] = false;
}.bind(this));
```

This means for every keydown I register the user and the conversation the user is typing in. My question is, how can I throttle only "events" with the same userId+conversationId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GroupBy](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/groupby.md) is probably what you are looking for. It creates a sequence of observable groups that share the same key. In your case create new observable group for every typing user in conversation and then throttle events from those observable groups.

```
onKeydownSource.groupBy(
    function (e) { return e.conversationId + '-' + e.userId; },
    function (e) { return e; }
)
.subscribe(function(obs) {
    obs.throttle(500).subscribe(function (e) {
        typingInConversations[e.conversationId][e.userId] = false;
    });
});
```

First parameter is a function to extract the key for each element. You may want to figure out some better one there. Second parameter is a function to map each source element to an element in an observable group. In your case pass elements as is.

Comment: Still have no idea how I can make it work. Your example will never trigger for single user/conversation combinations if another combination is emitted before the 500ms

Comment: Your question first seemed simpler that it actually was so I updated my answer from distinctUntilChanged to groupByUntil.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but to me it seems like every 500 seconds, a new "obs" will be created. I rather need the Rx.Oberservable.timer to reset everytime an event with the same key (e.conversationId + '-' + e.userId) occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, it's groupBy without until. If you change your answer, I'll accept it!